# Can you use a forward slash "/" in an XML attribute value via DTD?

Tags: xml, dtd

I have an atribute named item_category and I want to use as enumerated values ( h/w | s/w). Is that possible? And If it is how? Basically i tried:

```
<!ATTLIST item
    item_category (h/w | s/w) #REQUIRED>
```

but I get errors like `Expecting "|".` and `Missing attribute presence #IMPLIED, #Required...` and `Expecting ")".` so it actually doesnt take forward slash as a value.

Comment: Using it's html entity ? `h&#47;w | s&#47;w`

Comment: @LMC: That's not going to help -- still not allowed in an XML attribute name.

Comment: OP is asking about enumerations for the attribute value, not the name.

Comment: Well, at least that what is the *code* is attempting to do. @Toulis you may want to update the question to clarify that you are asking about attribute values, not names.

Comment: @MadsHansen:  Oops, I see that you're right that OP was asking about attribute values, not names -- my mistake.  Thanks for answering the actual question asked.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can directly.

The values for an enumeration in an `ATTLIST` have to be either `NOTATION` or `NMTOKEN`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttlistDecl

> [Definition: Enumerated attributes have a list of allowed values in their declaration ]. They must take one of those values. There are two kinds of enumerated attribute types:

> Enumerated Attribute Types
> [57]    EnumeratedType     ::=      [NotationType](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NotationType) | [Enumeration](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Enumeration)
>
> [58]       NotationType       ::=      'NOTATION' S '(' S? Name (S? '|' S? Name)* S? ')'   [VC: Notation Attributes]
> [VC: One Notation Per Element Type]
> [VC: No Notation on Empty Element]
> [VC: No Duplicate Tokens]
>
> [59]       Enumeration    ::=      '(' S? Nmtoken (S? '|' S? Nmtoken)* S? ')'  [VC: Enumeration]
> [VC: No Duplicate Tokens]

A `/` isn't allowed in the value of an `NMTOKEN`.

It is allowed as the value of a `NOTATION`.

```
<!NOTATION hw PUBLIC "h/w">
<!NOTATION sw PUBLIC "s/w">
<!ATTLIST item
    item_category NOTATION (hw|sw) #REQUIRED>
]>
```